# On Liquibase 4.16 script (SQL), can´t set value on autoincrement column on mysql 8

Tags: sql, mysql, liquibase

I´m trying to insert some records on a table, defined as something like this:

```sql
    CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
      `key` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `field` int NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`key`),
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I'm using a Liquibase with a SQL script like:

```sql
    INSERT INTO `mytable`
        (`key`, `field`)
    VALUES (0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3);
```

In other words, i want to set a AUTO_INCREMENT field on a new record with a specific value. That works perfectly on MySQL Workbench, but on Liquibase, it fails with something like:

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'mytable.PRIMARY'
```

The table is created previously in the script and is empty when the insert is executed. Is also empty after executing.

EDIT: I tried writing the changeset with the insert in XLM, instead of SQL, and the result is the same.
Furthermore, if I keep executing `update` (either with XLM or SQL) I get the same error, but on the next record. Like first on (0,4), then (1,5), etc. But when I query the table is emtpy, exept after the last execution (2,3), when it the query shows all the records inserted, but the Primary Key is incorrect. It´s the secuence generated by auto_increment (1, 2, 3).

Comment: The error message is clear you already have a key = 2

Comment: @P.Salmon I edited the question to clarify that the table is empty before and after executing the statement

Comment: 'You can also explicitly assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers, unless the NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO SQL mode is enabled' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html - is it set?

Comment: @P.Salmon Checking on MySQL workbench NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO is not enabled. But the problem was related to that, it was related to wanting to insert a 0 on the PK. If by example, begin with 2, there is no problem. The really weird thing is that the table stayed emtpy on Workbench unless I repeateadly executed "liquibase update". But anyway I will avoid setting the PK on 0 with liquibase. If you want, you can write the answer and I will accept it because you led me right to it. Thanks!